# How to use last clicked x/y coordinates in a qgis action?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, expression

I created an action (layer properties > actions) that opens an online map.

For the action I use this expression to dynamically generate the url of the map.

```
[% ürl" %]/?op=flyTo&cam=[% x($geometry)%],[% y($geometry) %],500.00&look=[% x($geometry)%],[% y($geometry)%],25.00
```

This works: the online map opens at the x/y position of the center of the object that you click.

For example: 
https://pointscene.com/scene/85300c83/share/8a7f7c68262ccc1fbebdc38031f68dc4/?op=flyTo&cam=93618.37,436479.01,500.00&look=93618.37,436479.01,25.00

Question:

Instead of opening the online map at the center of the object that I clicked, I would like to open the map at the exact mapcoördinates that I clicked.

I noticed these coördinates are shown in the info tool window, as 'derived' data. But I can't find them in the expression builder.

So: how do I use the last clicked coördinates in my action?

Answer (score 2):

`@click_x` and `@click_y` will give you those, however be aware they still only work on features and not just any place on the map.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that's exactly what I need. However instead of `@click_x` and `@click_y` I had to use `$clickx` and `$clicky`